# Resize and reposition window to span all monitors

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation

Hi all I am working on a small cross-platform hobby/educational project which takes screenshot of all monitors and overlays all monitors with one wide window. Now on Windows and GTK systems this is no problem. But I am having issues on OSX:

1. First major issue is that the window is not covering the non-work areas of the dock and the menubar at top.
2. It won't resize to span multiple monitors.

Is there any programattic way to accomplish this? Users really like when a screenshot is taken that it overlays all monitors with the capture and then they crop and click upload to image service etc. I just want to bring them the same experience on OSX.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OS X 10.9, Apple introduced a feature called "Displays have separate Spaces". See the Mission Control pane of System Preferences. It's on by default.

When that is on, no window can span multiple monitors. Even if it's programmatically set with an frame that does, it will only appear on the screen that contains the most area of the window. The window will be clipped to the frame of that screen.

So, you have to create a separate window for each screen.

From the [10.9 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#10_9Spaces):

> #### Spaces and Multiple Screens
>
> In 10.9, we have added a feature where
>   each screen gets its own set of spaces, and it is possible to switch
>   between spaces on one screen without perturbing the spaces on the
>   other screens. In this mode, a fullscreen window uses one screen, and
>   leaves the contents of any other screens unchanged. …
>
> When this feature is enabled, windows may not visibly span displays. 
>   A window will get assigned to the display containing the majority of
>   its geometry if programmatically positioned in a spanning position.  A
>   window will get assigned to the display containing the mouse if the
>   window is moved by the user.  A window clips to the edge of the
>   display, whether or not there is another adjacent display.

Also, since the menu bar appears on all screens, Apple changed the way windows are constrained to screens. Also, from the [10.9 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#X10_9Notes):

> #### constrainFrameRect:toScreen: now invoked for borderless windows
>
> Prior
>   to 10.9, the NSWindow method -[NSWindow constraintFrameRect:toScreen:]
>   was invoked only for windows with NSTitledWindowMask set in their
>   styleMask. In 10.9, this method is invoked for all windows. The
>   default implementation does a more limited constraining for non-titled
>   windows, as described in “NSWindows constrained to not intersect the
>   menu bar” below.
>
> #### NSWindows constrained to not intersect the menu bar
>
> In 10.9, in
>   support of the new multi-monitor architecture, windows are now
>   constrained to not intersect the menu bar on their containing space.
>   This restriction was already in place for titled windows, but it has
>   been extended to borderless windows whose level is at least
>   NSNormalWindowLevel but less than NSMainMenuWindowLevel. This behavior
>   is implemented in -[NSWindow constraintFrameRect:toScreen:]. You may
>   override that method in an NSWindow subclass to adjust or prevent this
>   constraining.

So, you either have to use a custom subclass of `NSWindow` which overrides `-constrainFrameRect:toScreen:` to return the unconstrained frame, or you have to set your window's `level` to `NSMainMenuWindowLevel` or higher.

Comment: Ah bogus! Thanks man. So if I request users to uncheck that checkbox can I do it programatically as one, and thats only way (asking user to uncheck? I can temporarily override, i just show window while user crops and uploads < 5sec)? Reason I need it one is I put in the window a huge canvas so now the user can make a selection/cropping across monitors.

Comment: Actually that window per screen isnt a bad idea i can make the canvas work with mousemove event listener which may be a bit intensive but doable. Is there anyway to make a window cover the dock and menubar at top? Do i have to set fullscreen? I want to not have to set fullscreen as that causes animation and slide over to new desktop space :(

Comment: You can't have the user uncheck that checkbox. The change doesn't take effect until the user logs out and back in. What I wrote about constraining the window frame was intended to answer the issue with covering the dock and menu bar. Either override that method or use a borderless window at a high window level.

Comment: My users are having hard time understanding the meaning of this, I noticed this setting does not require password, is it possible set this setting programatically without special user access? I do prompt my user I am setting this and they have to agree/disagree.

Comment: You ***really*** don't want to force your users to disable this setting. It's an important user experience feature. Personally, I don't like it and turn it off, but I'd be pissed if some application *required* that I have it the other way. That is, I'm sure there are people who prefer it on, and will be pissed if they have to turn it off just to use your software. In any case, I don't know if there's a way to change the setting programmatically, but as I said, it requires that the user logs out before it takes effect. Just work around it as I explained.

Comment: Ah ok thanks Ill do that, btw this is screencast of what I'm making: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9runhuVdqWE With multi windows with their own canvas element it gets much tricker but ill have to do it for osx :(

Comment: Boom baby! Got it!! Do you use Firefox Ken? :D Would you like to test it out? :D https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot thanks for all your help man it has helped me make some coool stuff!! users will be so happy! I did the multi window technique, win per monitor as you recommended :) And worked on algorithm so can do selections across monitors :D that was some dirty math ahah

Comment: Here we go Ken! Uploading to addons.moz :D Thank you so much I know I would love to see the work the people I help get to making. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/  I only have that one issue where if user does delayed shot like 10sec, then opens a full screen app, workspace scrolls over to that fullscreen app. And when timer gets to 0 it takes shot, but when i open the editor window it scrolls back to workspace 1  :( Do you have any ideas on how to avoid that? :( I want my editor to open on whatever workspace they are on :)

Comment: Hey there @Ken, I am setting the level to `MainMenu` and also tried `Dock` but then its not taking the size of the monitor. Is there any extra I have to do? Like `setMaxWidth` or something? Sorry about this, it turns out its a bug, i was using a fullscreen trick which isnt consistent.

Comment: "its not taking the size of the monitor"? What **is** happening? Have you tried using a custom window class which overrides `-constrainFrameRect:toScreen:` to return the passed-in frame rect unmodified?

Comment: Ahhh oh my gosh, it was buggy Firefox function. It wasn't working, i used ctypes to do the resizing and it worked. I have no idea by resizeTo and resizeBy from firefox functiosn wouldnt work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo   i have a side issue from this ill post question about it